# Hovering on icons with font awesome: how to change the size or edges of the icons?

Tags: css, font-size, font-awesome

I have the following code with font-awesome:

HTML:

```
<div> 
    <i class='icon-chevron-down font-big'></i>
</div>

<div>
    <i class='icon-chevron-down font-big'></i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.font-big {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 6px;
}
.font-big:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

The problem is that the icons overlap, as [you can see on this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sBDd/1/).

How can I make it so that the hovering behavior is correct: the bounds of each icon should not extend and overlap the other ?

Comment: The fiddle shows a sentence written, nothing more.. Did you try adding a margin just to one of them though?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fTdRS/

You could try putting the icons into an inner div similar to this example.

```
div.inner {
    xdisplay: block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
```